# Need to write expression in SSRS which need to filter my record based on the condition applied?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-expression

1. I have a column called `Booking` in my data set.
2. What I need is i need to filter booking start with `TR-AFP` alone from my `BOOKING` column.
3. So I need a parameter which need to have like this (TR-AFP AND ALL) when user select anyone it should show as per their condition.
4. Like if I select TR-AFP it should show only TR-AFP records in ssrs report, if i select all it should show all records except TR-AFP or including them.

Answer (score 0):

This is my Temporay data for your use case

[image]

create parameter as below

[image]

Now create row visibility expression as below

[image]

Note just for simplicity purpose I have made condition as if user selects TR-AFP then show records with only Category="electronics" and if user selects "ALL" then everything except category="electronics"

You just have to adjust according to your column and it's Value

```
=IIF(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value=1 and Fields!category.Value<>"electronics",true,
IIF(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value<>1 and Fields!category.Value="electronics",true,false))
```

Here is how it looks, Look for Right hand side, left hand one is just for your ref as database

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can try making a separate dataset just for the distinct booking entities. Declare that parameter in your original dataset, create temp table, join that temp table to the original table. Hope this works for you

@booking
Temp table
SELECT CAST(VALUE AS VARCHAR) AS Booking
--INTO #booking
--FROM string_split(@booking,',')

select .......
from......
JOIN #booking B on originalDS.booking=B.booking

in SSRS

Original DS > Parameters > Expression > =Join(Parameters!booking.Value,",")

Regards,